# What species is this spider?

Tags: species-identification, species, arachnology

[image: The Spider]

A friend of mine saw this monstrosity in Taiwan. The photo isn't very clear but you can't blame her considering it was the size of her face. Wanted to know what species it is so I know where they spawn and to stay away from those areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is called Nephila pilipes.

You can refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephila_pilipes) for more information

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged on the stack exchange sites. You can improve the answer by expanding on it.

Comment: Not sure how to expand on it. He asked for the name of the species and I answered.

Comment: @Casanova You could mention features that make this species identifiable.